# How to check if username exists in database or not without submitting the form using jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, validation, jsp

I am trying to check if username exists in database or not without submitting the form. But I am not getting success.
Below is my code.

controller1.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.regex.*"%>
<%-- <%@ page import="java.net.URLEncoder" session="false" %> --%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Controller</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <%
    String Username = request.getParameter("Username");
        session.setAttribute( "theName", Username );
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "");
                try{
                    Statement st = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs;
                    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from signupform where Username='" + Username + "'");
                if(rs.next()){
                    String usermessage = "Username already exists";
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("usermessage", usermessage);
                    response.sendRedirect("Signupform.jsp");
                }
                else{
                PreparedStatement ps = con. prepareStatement("insert into signupform(Username) values(?)");
                ps.setString(1, Username);
        if(Username.isEmpty())
        {
            String message = "Please fill all the fields";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("message", message);
            /* response.sendRedirect("Signupform.jsp?message="+ URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8")); */
            response.sendRedirect("Signupform.jsp");
        }
        else{
            ps.executeUpdate();
            response.sendRedirect("Welcome.jsp");
        }
                }
                }
    catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e);
    }
%>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The form used for providing input is shown in the code Signupform.jsp. It should immediately report in the same page whether the user exists or not when the user fill the respective field.

Signupform.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Register</title>
<link Rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class ="container">      
<div>
<form action="controller1.jsp" method = "POST">
Username <input type = "text" name = "Username" value="">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
<br>
<p>${usermessage}</p>
<c:remove var="usermessage" scope="session"/>

</form>
</div>
   </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cant you use AJAX?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I will be happy if pure JSP is possible.

Comment: What you have tried ? can you add that as well in your question ?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this is a gigantic security hole. You can't do DB queries like this; use PreparedStatement. Alternatively, fill in for username:

```
joe'; DROP TABLE signupform CASCADE; --
```

and your database will disappear.

You seem to know how preparedstatements work (you're using it for the insert). You have to use it everywhere, all your SQL pretty much has to be a single string constant. If you ever type `"SELECT ...." +...` stop. Don't do that.

What you want can't easily be done. That's not how the web works. The client is the client, the server is the server, they aren't in contact with each other unless you explicitly make it so.

The client would have to use javascript (code that runs on the client) to ask the server as-you-type, triggering off of the username field changing, which is itself tricky (there are a heck of a lot of ways to change a text field in a browser. For example, you can right click and select paste, so registering a keyboard handler is no good).

Easy-ish solution: Use `setInterval` to check every ±200 milliseconds or so. Don't do anything if the field hasn't been modified since the last time you checked, and don't check if an ajax call is in progress. Otherwise, send an ajax call to the server to ask, and manipulate the DOM to reflect this.

You're going to have to learn javascript, which.. is not exactly a thing you'll get done in an hour. This really boils down to: "How do I write webapps". That question has answers, but SO is not a good place for that. That's more a matter for books and very long tutorials.